# A definite integral involving $\exp(-a\cosh x)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Wolfram alpha can not integrate the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty x^n \exp(-a\cosh x)dx$$
Thanks-
Mike

Comment: do you mean cos or cosh?

Comment: Bessel functions might be relevant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: It is $\cosh x$

Comment: I wish there exists an analytical formula for this integral.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of this relation. By the way I checked Wikipedia and have not found anything that is directly related to this integral.

Comment: Even for $n=0$, it seems that there is no closed form for the antiderivative.

Comment: @mike: where did this integral come from?

Comment: It came up when I am searching for an approximate to Riemann $\Xi(z)$ function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *By the way I checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and have not found anything that is directly related to this integral.*

So I assume you missed the part where $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp(-a\cosh(x))~dx=K_0(a),~$ which is what we

get when letting $b=0$ in $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp(-a\cosh(x))\cosh(bx)~dx=K_b(a).~$ Now, what happens if

we differentiate twice both expressions with regard to *b*, in $b=0$? We get $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-a\cosh(x)}dx=$

$=\bigg[\dfrac{d^2}{db^2}K_b(a)\bigg]_{b=0}~$ so, by repeating the process a number of times, for even values of $n=2k$, we

have a closed form in terms of even order derivatives of the [Bessel *K* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: You should be able to take the first derivative wrt $b$, divide by $b$, and then take the limit as $b \to 0$ to get the case $n=1$.

Comment: I am aware the $K_b(z)$ part, but miss the differentiation and limiting part. Nice solution!